# send python html mail doesn't view message of the mail

Tags: php, python, python-2.7, html-email

i have this python send html mail, and within this code, i can send email but the body of the message is blank.

below is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import MySQLdb
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime

def timestamp():
        now = datetime.now()
        return now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
def write_log(log):
        date_today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 

    if os.path.isfile('logs/log.'+date_today+'.txt') == True:
            wlog = open('logs/log.'+date_today+'.txt','a')
            wlog.writelines('\n'+timestamp()+' - '+log)
    else:
            wlog = open('logs/log.'+date_today+'.txt','w')
            wlog.writelines(timestamp()+' - '+log)

def login():
    now = time.strftime("%c")
    username = "email@email.com"
    pwd = 'password'
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("email@email.com",587)
    smtpserver.login(username, pwd)

db_ip = 'localhost'
db_user = 'USER'
db_pass = 'DBPASSWORD'
db_dbase = 'DBASE'

while 1:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(db_ip,db_user,db_pass,db_dbase)
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM form_number WHERE tag = 2")
    data = cur.fetchall()

    for row in data:
        recipient = row[6]
        sender = 'NO REPLY EMAIL<noreply@email.com>'
        assigned_person = row[5]
        header = 'Date: ' + now + '\n' + 'To:' + recipient + '\n' + 'From: ' +sender + '\n' + 'Subject:Liquidation record of ' + assigned_person +  '\n'
        msg = """Content-type: text/html
                    Subject: liquidation for """+ row[5] +"""
                            <font color='#000000'>
                                """ + row[5] +  """ has sent you a request.
                                to view click on the link below.
                             </font>"""
        message = header + msg
        print message
        smtpserver.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
        cur.execute("UPDATE form_number SET tag = 3, time_sent = '" + now + "' WHERE form_number = '" + str(row[0]) + "'")

    db.commit()
    db.close()
    time.sleep(15)

def run():
    try:
        login()
    except:
        pass

run()
#login()
```

i can successfully send email to my desired recipient but when the recipient receive the email, it has only have a blank mesage. any comments will do. thanks in advance!

Comment: PLEASE DON'T YELL AT US

Comment: @PatrickCollins i'm not yelling. i'm sorry.

Comment: IT LOOKS LIKE YOU STILL ARE, MAYBE YOU SHOULD EDIT YOUR QUESTION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white space in your message is incorrect. I believe your message looks like this:

```
From: NO REPLY SMSGT<noreply@smsgt.com>
Subject:Liquidation record of assigned_person
Content-type: text/html
                Subject: liquidation for John
                        <font color='#000000'>
                            John has sent you a request.
                            to view click on the link below.
                         </font>
```

But it should look like this:

```
From: NO REPLY SMSGT<noreply@smsgt.com>
Subject:Liquidation record of assigned_person
Content-type: text/html
Subject: liquidation for John

<font color='#000000'>
John has sent you a request.
to view click on the link below.
 </font>
```

Try replacing your assignment to `msg` like so:

```
msg = \
"""Content-type: text/html
Subject: liquidation for """+ row[5] +"""

<font color='#000000'>
""" + row[5] +  """ has sent you a request.
to view click on the link below.
</font>"""
```

Comment: i tried to clear the whitespace just like your sample above but instead my msg was transformed into a textfile.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is use python's [email](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) module instead of building the email by hand. It will take care of correctly building the envelope for HTML vs. plain text. The documentation there even shows how to send an HTML email with smtplib (scroll down to the part that says "how to create an HTML message").

Also, be careful of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) on this line!

```
cur.execute("UPDATE form_number SET tag = 3, time_sent = '" + now + "' WHERE form_number = '" + str(row[0]) + "'")
```

In this case you might (?) be safe because you have control over `now` and `row[0]`, but it's **always** better and more secure to use a prepared statement and pass in the values as parameters instead of concatenating them into the query.

Here's how to use prepared statements with MySQLdb:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#Python_DB-API

(ignore that the example is sqlite3, it works the same because they both follow python's DBAPI standard)

Comment: when i try to execute my python. my database updates and i have received an email, my only problem is that i received only a blank message. as in blank message.

Comment: I think the email is blank because the message you're creating (message = header + msg) isn't a valid email. If you use the `email` module I linked to then you don't need to worry about building it correctly by hand. If you really want to build the email manually then you should read RFC822, etc. to make sure you've got the format correct.

Answer (score -1):

Unless I'm not mistaking, `"""` are the equivalent of code comments in Python.

So essentially you're commenting out the message.

*It has been a long time since I coded in py. Don't hurt me...*

Comment: This is not quite right. Triple quotes (`"""`, `'''`) are used to define strings, same as single quotes (`'`, and `"`). Some people use it to comment out code, but in this case he's correctly assigning a string to `msg`.

Comment: if you read out the code @lost-theory, i have print the message and  when i run the code, i successfully print out the whole message, my real problem is when i received the email i have problem on my code